# What does an 'eye for the ladies' mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

What does it mean when a guy has an 'eye for the ladies'

Comment: To [have an eye for](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+eye+for) *- to have a taste or an inclination for someone or something*. This is general reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally implying somewhat euphemistically that the person whom it refers to, the one who supposedly has such an eye, is a bit of a Lothario.  Or maybe more than just a bit.